# How do I keep my custom nav bar at bottom of screen in code without IB

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, resize

I have a custom nav bar that I want to pinned to the bottom of the screen when its expanded for iphone 5.  I only know how to do this properly in IB and have inherted code from a deveoper,

Ive tried:

```
ICNavbarView *navBarView = [[ICNavbarView alloc] init];
navBarView.delegate = self;
CGRect navBarFrame = navBarView.frame;
navBarFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - navBarFrame.size.height;
navBarView.frame = navBarFrame;
[self.view addSubview:navBarView];

////////resize/metrics of Navbar////////
[navBarView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
```

Nav bar wont budge! Am I missing a method for moving the nav bar down with the screen without resizing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
[navBarView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
```

to:

```
[navBarView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
```

Comment: Brilliant, thought that refered to the top bar! sorted thank you!